# Passing Grails params to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I want to pass URL parameters used in a GSP to a jQuery-function. I have found a solution that works but my gut tells me using global Javascript variables isn´t a good idea.

GSP - making params.id from Grails available for Javascript as a global variable:

```
<g:javascript >
    var categoryId = ${params.id}
</g:javascript>
```

Using this variable in a jQuery-function:

```
<g:javascript src="views/visual.js"/>
```

Javascript:

```
// Call with URL using the global variable defined in the GSP
$.getJSON(
    "../visualJson?id=" + categoryId,
    function (data) {
    // Some code.
});
```

What is the idiomatic Grails way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not necessarily specific to Grails, why don't you pass the variable into a function? Say:

In "views/visual.js" you have:

```
var someFunction = function(categoryId)
{
    // Call with URL using the global variable defined in the GSP
    $.getJSON(
        "../visualJson?id=" + categoryId,
        function (data) {
        // Some code.
    });
}
```

And thus you pass the value by calling the function `someFunction('${params.id}')` in your app.

Comment: Or you can create a javascript object that holds the variables - that way you dont have global variables.

Comment: But that object will still be available globally and that could be overwritten by other scripts, especially if you're using 3rd party scripts (worst case scenario of course)

Comment: Well in that case any of your script can be overwritten by other scripts.

Comment: @Ahmed you could keep the JavaScript object within your own namespace making it far less likely to be touched by external script code.