# How to get the action name (or view name) in Grails from Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I read [here](http://fillinginthegaps.wordpress.com/2009/01/17/how-to-get-the-current-controller-or-action-in-grails/), that in the GSP we could write:

```
${params.action}
```

From the GSP, we could call a Javascript function with `${params.action}` as parameter (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134466/passing-grails-params-to-javascript)).

Is there any other way to get the action name without passing parameters from the GSP view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the desire to reduce application code happening in the views, but to allow the proper components to handle what they handle (separation of concerns), it is the best way to have the controller pass the action name to the view via a model.

The client-side script otherwise has only the url and a loose sense of the route table compared to the server-side which must know exactly the route table.

If you still feel it best to use client-side script, window.location provides the url.  To parse the url, javascript's string.split using '/' as the delimiter should suffice, the following snippet should help:

```
var url = window.location;
var urlParts = url.split('/');
var controller = urlParts[3];
var action = urlParts[4];
```

Comment: wow. Nice answer. I did a litle change to make it work: `var url = window.location.pathname;` (and `var controller = urlParts[2];...`). Thank you!

Comment: The initial suggestion of passing the name to the view is fine, but the js example is nonsense. Firstly the code is all wrong, and assumes that there are no parameters, and doesn't check the length of the array.